# Indenting an in-line list: how to indent entries of itemize* from enumitem

Tags: indentation, enumitem

I am trying to indent itemize* entries, which is an attribute of the enumitem package. The web suggested that adding a leftmargin flag like this would accomplish this, but it leaves things undiented. `\begin{itemize*}[leftmargin=-.5in]`

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setmainfont[Color=primary, ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
\newcommand{\customit}[1]{\color{primary}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-LigIta}\selectfont #1 \normalfont}

\begin{document}
\location{August 2009-Present | Southern California}
\begin{itemize*}[leftmargin=-.5in]
  \item{Ableton} \item{ProTools} \item{Logic Pro} \item{Grage Band} \item{StudioOne} \item{Reaper} \item{Audacity} \item{Digital Performer}
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

Or see overloaf template here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xstqgvbkqvgr

Comment: What do you mean exactly with ‘indenting’ here? This is an online list.

Comment: I'd like the in-line list to be indented relative to the \location tab above it, sort of like how the normal itemize works.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `adjustwidth` environment, from `changepage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\location{August 2009-Present | Southern California}0.5in
\lipsum[11]\bigskip
\begin{adjustwidth}{.5in}{}
\begin{itemize*}[itemjoin=;\quad]
  \item{Ableton} \item{ProTools} \item{Logic Pro} \item{Grage Band} \item{StudioOne} \item{Reaper} \item{Audacity} \item{Digital Performer.}
\end{itemize*}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]